# Select list of grouped rows, showing content of most recent

Tags: mysql

Not the best title, I apologise.

Table structure:

**messages**

- id - int
- message - varchar
- user - varchar
- date - varchar
- from - varchar

**contacts**

- contactId - int
- contactUser - varchar
- contactName - varchar
- contactFrom - varchar

My query currently is:

```
 SELECT
     messages1.`from`,
     messages1.`message`,
     messages1.`date` AS d,
     messages2.`count`,
     contacts.`contactId`,
     contacts.`contactName`,
     contacts.`contactFrom`
 FROM messages AS messages1,
   (
          SELECT
              MAX(`date`) AS maxdate,
             `from`,
             COUNT(*) AS `c`
          FROM messages
          WHERE
             `user` = 'MYUSER'
          GROUP BY `from`
   ) AS messages2
LEFT JOIN contacts ON
   (
       contacts.`contactUser` = 'MYUSER' AND
       contacts.`contactsFrom` = messages2.`from`
   )
WHERE
   messages1.`from`= messages2.`from` AND
   messages1.`date` = messages2.`date`
ORDER BY `date` DESC;
```

However, when a user has the same contact 'from' for two different users, they will get the same 'conversation' twice.

Eg:

If the following data exists:

**contacts**

```
| contactId | contactUser |  contactName | contactFrom |
|-----------|-------------|--------------|-------------|
|     1     |   giggsey   |  MyNameOne   | +1234567890 |
|     2     |   giggsey   | MySecondName | +1234567890 |
```

**messages**

```
|  id  |  message  |   user   |    date    |     from     |
|------|-----------|----------|------------|--------------|
|   1  |     h1    | giggsey  | 111111111  | +1234567890  |
|   2  |     h2    | giggsey  | 111111113  | +1234567890  |
|   3  |   random  | giggsey  | 111111116  | +9999992234  |
|   4  |     h3    | giggsey  | 111111119  | +1234567890  |
```

Then the query returns:

```
|     from    | message |      d    | count | contactId |  contactName | contactFrom |
|-------------|---------|-----------|-------|-----------|--------------|-------------|
| +1234567890 |    h3   | 111111119 |   3   |     1     |   MyNameOne  | +1234567890 |
| +1234567890 |    h3   | 111111119 |   3   |     2     | MySecondName | +1234567890 |
| +9999992234 |  random | 111111116 |   3   |  (NULL)   |     (NULL)   |   (NULL)    |
```

As you can see above, it is returning the same 'conversation' twice, but once for each duplicate of the contact.

I'm pretty sure it's because of the JOIN, but I can't seem to work out why.

Comment: The identifiers in your query don't match the identifiers in your text. For example, your query refers to `contacts.from`, but your text doesn't mention a `from` field on `contacts`.

Comment: @ruakh Same as above, copy/paste fail.

Comment: You may find you get a better response if you clarify your schema. Your messages table has fields `user` and `from`. Might these be better represented as `to_user_id` and `from_user_id`? The `date` field - is this a DATE field? If it is a DATETIME field perhaps it would be better named as `sent` or `created`. Why the mix of naming styles of field names - some prefixed with table name some not? The mix of join syntaxes in your query is really horrible. If you want people to make an effort at answering your question perhaps you should put a bit more effort into asking it?

Comment: @nnichols Thanks for the feedback, I've updated the question, does that make it more clear?

Comment: Thank you for updating the question. It is much clearer now and as expected. Your join `contacts.contactsFrom = messages2.from` is from one row to two rows. There is no way of pulling a single record from contacts as there is no foreign key in messages that links to a unique key in contacts. If you wish to treat contactFrom as a key in this way it must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using a subquery instead of just reading from the table.

```
 SELECT
     messages1.`from`,
     messages1.`message`,
     messages1.`date` AS d,
     messages2.`count`,
     contacts.`contactId`,
     contacts.`contactName`,
     contacts.`contactFrom`
 FROM messages AS messages1,
   (
          SELECT
              MAX(`date`) AS maxdate,
             `from`,
             COUNT(*) AS `c`
          FROM messages
          WHERE
             `user` = 'MYUSER'
          GROUP BY `from`
   ) AS messages2
LEFT JOIN
  (
      SELECT
          *
      FROM
         `contacts`
      GROUP BY `contactsFrom`
  ) contacts ON
   (
       contacts.`contactUser` = 'MYUSER' AND
       contacts.`contactsFrom` = messages2.`from`
   )
WHERE
   messages1.`from`= messages2.`from` AND
   messages1.`date` = messages2.`date`
ORDER BY `date` DESC;
```